# Prevent images from saving to database instead of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, character-encoding

Via proxy I try to parse some html. For one of them, I get specific element through `jQuery`:

```
var site = 'http://www.kartabu.com/pl/index.php?filter=random'
var url = 'http://localhost/taboo.blue-world.pl/admin/proxy.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(site)

$.ajax({
    url      : url,
    type     : 'GET',
    dataType : 'html'
}).done(function(res) {

    var div = $('<div></div>');
    div.html(res);

    var to_guess = div.find('.card_top_name').first().text().toLowerCase();

    console.log(to_guess); 
});
```

This is my **proxy.php** file:

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://', '', $url); // Avoid accessing the file system
echo file_get_contents($url); // You should probably use cURL. The concept is the same though
```

The result prints on console `pe�ny` instead of `pełny`. Since on the source site there is `pełny`. How can I fix this? Where is the source of the problem?

The below line also doesn't fix the problem:

```
var to_guess = encodeURIComponent(div.find('.card_top_name').first().text().toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",` in your ajax. like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url      : url,
    type     : 'GET',
    dataType : 'html',
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
}).done(function(res) {

    var div = $('<div></div>');
    div.html(res);

    var to_guess = div.find('.card_top_name').first().text().toLowerCase();

    console.log(to_guess); 
});
```

this will result to language independent results.

Comment: Still prints images, didnt help.

Comment: You suggest that it is working, right? but maybe this is something else? Because when I `console.log(res)` there are images yet.

Comment: i need to add up a screen shot here, where can i do that? i'll show you my result console.

Comment: better provide your html as well. will check using that.

Comment: Cannot this is very ugly and will trash my question.

Comment: okay, but that was needful, to check out your need and to go through your problem.

Comment: I tried to copy and paste, but it doesnt want to be parsed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add following header to `proxy.php`:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2');
```

Now it works great.